# AutoFill aka auto login in Flutter

Tags: ios, flutter, credentials, autofill

I would like to use auto login or AutoFill as called on iOS. I'm a native Android developer and not really sure about iOS. For Android I implemented smartlock for passwords. I'm not very familiar with iOS development, but [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/password_autofill/enabling_password_autofill_on_a_text_input_view) says something about a flag which needs to be set. do I understand [this bug](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/43041) correctly that this feature is not yet implemented in Flutter? It also seems that there was a [related PR](https://github.com/flutter/engine/pull/13878) which was never merged does anyone know the current status?

Is there any workaround I could use to set that flag? I didn't really understand how the views are build in Flutter on iOS. I thought that they were just rendered a bit like a game (with canvas or similar things), but then there would be no option to set such UI flags.

Comment: I guess invoking [`SecRequestSharedWebCredential(...)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/1617896-secrequestsharedwebcredential) from a custom plugin is the best option...